# Rem values rendering differently in modern browsers?

Tags: html, css

Ssomebody know, My 1 rem unit is rendered in different way in Chrome and Firefox. If check Devtools in Computed: in Chrome 1 rem is equal 16 and in Firefox is 17.6? Thanks

Comment: share the code the produce such output

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/4xsL6h9c/here.png

Comment: Please attempt to create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: In codepen it works fine, just in vs code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously those are the default browser settings. However, Firefox usually also has 16px as a default. Check your preferences and check if there is any zooming applied.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/HLmSt885/default-font.png

Comment: looks like you activated zooming

Comment: Yes, it was zooming. Because the lack of practice spend a bit of time before understand that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

According to the W3C spec the definition for one rem unit is:

Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element. When specified on the font-size property of the root element, the rem units refer to the property’s initial value.

in other words you have to set font-family in pixel for parent element or for root element.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: do you have an answer or you just didn't understand my answer? he should set `:root {font-family: 16px;}`